# Xcode omitting parameters names of block

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, block

I have a block property that looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^indexChangeBlock)(NSInteger index);
```

When I try to set the value for this property, Xcode autocomplete will omit the parameter name leaving me with something like this:

```
[self.segmentedControl3 setIndexChangeBlock:^(NSInteger) {
    code
}];
```

Then Xcode shows a `Parameter name omitted` error. I'm aware that I can solve this by adding the parameter name manually to make it look like this:

```
[self.segmentedControl3 setIndexChangeBlock:^(NSInteger index) {
    code
}];
```

My questions is, how can I make Xcode add the parameters names automatically. Or in other words, prevent it from removing them.

Comment: But the type of `indexChangeBlock` *is* just `void (^)(NSInteger)`. There is no "parameter name" in a function type or block type. It is meaningless to the language.

Comment: Yes, it's meaningless to the language but it's useful for autocomplete in Xcode, specially when your code is going to be used by others.

Comment: FWIW, I just tested the above syntax in Xcode 12.5.1, and the auto-complete does include the parameter name now.

Comment: Glad to know it's been fixed 8 years later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

possible solution:

```
typedef void (^IndexChangeBlock)(NSInteger index);
```

and define your property with

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) IndexChangeBlock indexChangeBlock;
```

and if you add

```
- (void)setIndexChangeBlock:(IndexChangeBlock)indexChangeBlock;
```

everything should work

Comment: Xcode will autocomplete that to `[self.segmentedControl3 setIndexChangeBlock:(IndexChangeBlock)indexChangeBlock]`, so it's even more annoying.

Comment: edited my answer, sadly you have to add the setter-declaration manually

Comment: Works like a charm now, thanks! It's also worth mentioning that it could also work without the typedef. Just the property and the setter method `- (void)setIndexChangeBlock:(void (^)(NSInteger index))indexChangeBlock;` will do.

Answer (score 1):

In exacerbated frustration, I made a macro consolidating this gross process..

```
#define BlockProperty(SIGNATURE,TYPENAME,varname,Varname) typedef SIGNATURE; @property (nonatomic,copy) TYPENAME varname; - (void) set##Varname:(TYPENAME)_
```

Now what Previously would've required (for proper autocompletion)..

```
typedef void(^OnEvent)(BOOL ok,id result);
@property (nonatomic,copy) OnEvent varname;
- (void) setVarname:(OnEvent)_;
```

is simply

```
BlockProperty(void(^OnEvent)(BOOL ok, id result),OnEvent,varname,VarName);
```

QUITE a bit easier, less verbose, AND you get the benefit of the typedef AND and you don't have to create the unsightly, theoretically unneeded setter declaration!

If you WANT to reuse a "type" you'll need another one (which this time will only take THREE parameters (as the block type cannot be redeclared).

```
#define BlockProp(TYPENAME,varname,Varname) @property (nonatomic,copy) TYPENAME varname; - (void)  set##Varname:(TYPENAME)_

BlockProp(OnEvent,anotherVar,AnotherVar);
```

You could just create a new block type (name) for each property even if their signatures match (using the first macro), but that's kind of gross.  Enjoy!