# How to auto-generate parameter names when Swift closures are exposed to Objective-C?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm writing some Swift code as follows:

```
@objc public class SwiftClass: NSObject {
    @objc func method(completion: (Int) -> Void) {
        completion(100)
    }
}
```

Then I need to call this method from another class written in Objective-C. However, when I type this method name, Xcode auto-complete it as follows:

```
@implementation ObjectiveCClass

- (void)testMethod {
    SwiftClass *obj = [SwiftClass new];
    [obj methodWithCompletion:^(NSInteger) { // Xcode complains here: Parameter name omitted
            
    }];
}

@end
```

The closure parameter name is missing when it is exported to Objective-C, so I have to manually specify a name to it, like `^(NSInteger aNum)`.

So is there any way to auto-generate this missing closure parameter?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Swift. Objective-C doesn't seem to do that in the first place. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440344/xcode-omitting-parameters-names-of-block

Comment: @Sweeper I believe that may be true a few years ago, because I just did some tests in my Xcode with pure Objective-C, the parameters can correctly show up.

Comment: @Sweeper - Objective-C does do this (if your block definition includes names for the parameters).